# configure multiple email domains to send and receive emails ODOO

Tags: email, odoo

I am using Helpdesk module  odoo 16.

We have 2 Support teams and both using different email domain

Support Team 1 : send and receive email on "
support@ domain1.com"

Support Team 2 : send and receive email on
"support@ domain2.com"

How to do this configuration on Help desk teams ?

Comment: That's not possible by configuration, because Odoo does not support multiple mail domains on one company.

Comment: Can you just do support2@domain1.com and have the mail server forward the email from support2@domain1.com to support@domain2.com?

Comment: This question is more suited for the Superuser SE